# Save scroll page phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, mobile

i use phonegap in application, one of page show item in listview jquery.
if i have 50 items and user scrolling and press item, detail page item will show.
my question, is possible we save previous last position scroll, so when user press back button, they dont see first item again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery Mobile you could store the current scroll position when the page is hidden (added the check in there as there may be certain pages that you want to retain the scroll position, and other times when you want to let it reset):

```
$("#myListPage").bind('pagebeforehide', function (event, data) {
    if (data.nextPage[0].id === "myItemDetailsPage") {
        // Store the scroll position, in case we want to go back
        myPage.scrollPosition = $("#myListPage-myList").scrollTop();
    }
});
```

Then when the page is shown:

```
$("#myListPage").bind('pageshow', function () {
    $("#myListPage-myList").scrollTop(myPage.scrollPosition);
});
```

Although I should say that I haven't needed to do this at times, and often I have to do the opposite - call `scrollTop(0)` to force the page to return to the top.